# Haskell Recursive Minimax Tree

Tags: algorithm, haskell, recursion, minimax

I'm trying to write a Tic Tac Toe program in Haskell, using the minimax algorithm. I constructed my own "Rose a" data type as follows:

```
data Rose a = a :> [Rose a]
```

This is the data type in which I want to 'store' my minimax tree. I understand how the minimax algorithm works, but can't seem to implement it in a recursive function.

```
minimax :: Player -> Rose Board -> Rose Int
minimax p (r :> [])   | hasWinner r == Just p              = 1  :> []
                      | hasWinner r == Just (nextPlayer p) = (-1) :> []
                      | otherwise                          = 0  :> []
minimax p (r :> rs)   = maximum(map root xs) :> xs
    where xs = map (minimax' (nextPlayer p)) rs

minimax' :: Player -> Rose Board -> Rose Int
minimax' p b@(r :> []) = minimax p b
minimax' p   (r :> rs) = minimum(map root xs) :> xs
    where xs = map (minimax p) rs
```

The "Player" is also a self-constructed data type, which can be of value P1 or P2. The "hasWinner" function checks if a given "Board" (data type which can hold a Tic Tac Toe board) has a winner, and returns either Maybe P1 or Maybe P2, or Nothing.

This "minimax" function I wrote is not giving me errors, but the result is not correct. Where is the flaw in my minimax implementation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You aren't switching between the two players correctly. `minimax' p b@(r :> []) = minimax p b` is wrong. `map (minimax p) rs` in `minimax'` doesn't switch to the other player for the maximizing half.

I'd recommend writing this out explicitly for `P1` (trying to maximize) and `P2` (trying to minimize).

The endgame can assign the winner without caring about which player is currently playing

```
minimax :: Player -> Rose Board -> Rose Int
minimax p (r :> [])   | hasWinner r == Just P1 = 1    :> []
                      | hasWinner r == Just P2 = (-1) :> []
                      | otherwise              = 0    :> []
```

Player `P1` is trying to maximize

```
minimax P1 (r :> rs) = maximum (map root xs) :> xs
    where xs = map (minimax (nextPlayer p)) rs
```

Player `P2` is trying to minimize

```
minimax P2 (r :> rs) = minimum (map root xs) :> xs
    where xs = map (minimax (nextPlayer p)) rs
```

Comment: Hi Cirdec, thanks so much for your reply. Your code seems logical, however, when I test the minimax function giving P1 and an example Board for input, my minimax tree is filled with ' 1 '. But the example Board actually has scenarios where P2 wins, which means there should also be '-1' in the tree... I double checked if the "hasWinner" function works, and after some tests, it seems to work correctly.

Comment: If `r` is the move chosen by `P1`, `rs` are the moves available to `P2`, `P2` is trying to `minimize`. Perhaps `P1` needs to consider how the other player would choose a move instead of choosing the one `P1` likes best for `P2` to make.

Comment: Isn't that practically the same as minimizing P2's move? How would I implement your theory in my code?

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of testing and being confused, I found out that the function which created the Game Tree had some flaws. After debugging that, the algorithm suggested by Cirdec worked correctly!

Comment: can you share your repo?