# How to create function minimax in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, minimax

I have been struggeling with creating a minimax function in Haskell and couldn't find any great alternatives on SO, hence why I am asking:

I want to create the following function:

```
minimax :: Player -> Rose Board -> Rose Int
```

I want to get a RoseTree of Integers, those have to be either 1, 0 or -1 (a move can either be good, neutral or bad for the player that has the turn.

```
(root :> leaves)               -- constructor of a Rose
(board :> boards)              -- constructor of a Rose Board
(Int :> Ints)                  -- constructor of a Rose Int
```

I have written the function hasWinner, minimum' and maximum' to make things easier:

```
hasWinner :: Board -> Maybe Player

minimum' :: [Int] -> Int
minimum' (x:xs) | x == -1 = -1
                | otherwise = minimum' xs

maximum' :: [Int] -> Int
maximum' (x:xs) | x == 1 = 1
                | otherwise = maximum' xs
```

Further I think my base case is the following:

```
minimax player (board :> []) = (0 :> [])
```

At the moment this is where I am at:

```
minimax player (board :> boards)| maximum' [(isWinner player b (minimax' player)) | (b :> bs) <- boards] == 1 = _
                                | minimum' [(isWinner player b (minimax' player)) | (b :> bs) <- boards] == -1 = _
                                | otherwise = _
                 where   minimax' player     | player == P1 = P2
                                             | otherwise = P1
                         isWinner p1 board p2    | hasWinner board == Just p1 = 1
                                                 | hasWinner board == Just p2 = -1
                                                 | otherwise = 0
```

I just can't seem to figure out what should happen when I found a board that is either won, lost or has no consequences. So how would I call the minimax function again with the right Rose Board?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Ramon

Answer (score 2):

I actually found another post discussing the same problem I have here: [Haskell Recursive Minimax Tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39798342/haskell-recursive-minimax-tree)

The answer was the following:

```
minimax :: Player -> Rose Board -> Rose Int
minimax p (r :> [])   | hasWinner r == Just P1 = 1    :> []
                      | hasWinner r == Just P2 = (-1) :> []
                      | otherwise              = 0    :> []
minimax P1 (r :> rs) = maximum (map root xs) :> xs
    where xs = map (minimax (nextPlayer P1)) rs

minimax P2 (r :> rs) = minimum (map root xs) :> xs
    where xs = map (minimax (nextPlayer P2)) rs
```

I hope at least this could help someone else in the future.
The functions that were used in this answer are:

```
root :: Rose a -> a
root (a :> bs) = a 

nextPlayer :: Player -> Player
nextPlayer P1 = P2
nextPlayer P2 = P1

hasWinner :: Board -> Maybe Player

minimum :: Ord a => [a] -> a
maximum :: Ord a => [a] -> a
```

cheers!